# Could not import module after using CocoaPods to install modules

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I was using CocoaPods to install `SDWebImage` and `CountdownLabel`, but those modules I installed could not be imported in the beginning of my Swift file.

The following are my codes:

```
import UIKit

import CountdownLabel

class.... {
..
..
}
```

It will prompt out an error, which says `Cannot load underlying module for 'CountdownLabel` ". Does anyone have any idea about this symptom?

1. I have make sure that I opened the file with .xcworkspace
2. pod install returns no error

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Xcode. Try to clean (Ctrl+Cmd+C) and re-build (Cmd+R) the project, that always worked for me.

Comment: I tried but with no luck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean the product, clean the build folder and build again. If that does not work try re-installing from CocoaPods. But don't forget to add to `use_frameworks` inside your Podfile.

You can clean the build folder with `Alt + Command + Shift + K` or press `Alt` then open `Product` drop down menu from Xcode than select `Clean Build Folder`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Do yo have the following code in your Podfile?
if not then add this code on Top of your Podfile.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
```

Comment: Yes, I never edit the Podfile, I just added the following in.

  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'CountdownLabel'

Comment: Did you add the following lines? Because with swift yo need to use Frameworks instead of librairies.

Answer (score 0):

Clear `Derived data` from `xcode` & reopen `xcode`. 
Clean then build project.

Comment: Here comes a quick update. After deleting Derived Data, and reopening xcode, the error disappear at that time. But it will go back when trying to code the component in the module. I tried several times on cleaning and building this project, but it didnt work. any idea?

Comment: Which version of xcode you are using? which swift version you are using?